# What is an optimal solution to store many versioned XML documents?

Tags: database, nosql

I need to store many XML documents identified by a unique name, and keep track of their versions. I need to have an access to every document (read, update, delete) through some RESTful API. I need to maintain access control (read/write permissions) for every document (or groups of them).

Is there any solution on the market for these needs?

Btw, other supplementary features would be welcome, like XSD-validation of every new incoming change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've found so far:

- [eXist](http://www.exist-db.org/)
- [xDB](https://community.emc.com/community/edn/xmltech)
- [MarkLogic](http://www.marklogic.com/product/marklogic-server.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could look into **CouchDB**: http://www.couch.io/

Answer (score 0):

You can look at github.com/dscape/facade for an open source project using REST + versioning. I'm doing JSON but XML in MarkLogic would be even simpler